# iis7.5 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf" cause connection reset

Tags: iis-7.5, content-type

I'm using IIS to send a pdf document (generated by abcpdf 8) in classical asp.

Nothing gets to the browser.

- FF: The connection was reset - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
- IE: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage - Internet Connectivity has been lost
- Chrome: This web page is not available - Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

This is the code:

```
Set theDoc = CreateObject("ABCpdf8.Doc") 
theDoc.FontSize = 96
thedoc.AddText "Hello World"

theData = theDoc.GetData()

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf" '<-- culprit?
Response.AddHeader "content-length", UBound(theData) - LBound(theData) + 1
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyPDF.PDF"
Response.BinaryWrite theData
```

If I comment out the ContentType line, the browser loads the binary data, but of course the data is displayed within the browser and is unreadable in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague from work resolved this one.

```
Response.BinaryWrite
Response.flush  '<-- this fixes it.
```

If anyone knows why this works please add a comment.